# Node server and npm is not running on Windows 12 EC2 instance in AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, npm, node-modules

I am running following command in User Data but I don't see that npm is installing npm_module and also not running node server.I have verified that node is already installed and PATH is already set.My Node code and pacakge.json is under 'MyNodeServer' folder.

$ctiServerDir="D:\Apps\CTICloud\MyNodeServer"
mkdir $ctiServerDir
npm set proxy= myproxy
npm set https-proxy=myhttpsprxy
Set-Location $ctiServerDir 
npm install
npm start

Comment: What version of nodejs you are using? What is npm version? What error you see when you run node application?

Comment: npm version 3.10.10 and node v6.11.3

Comment: It looks like node is installed under system account and instance is up with system account so I am not sure how to run nodejs under system account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by putting & 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd' --version command.It worked